# Retrieve the author of the last comments

Tags: laravel

I want to retrieve the name of the person who posted 
the last comment in a topic for a forum.
This is what I do at PhpMyAdmin and that works so I get the right values:

```
select commentaires.auteur 
from commentaires inner join sujets on commentaires.sujet_id = sujets.id
where commentaires.id = (
    select max(commentaires.id)
    from commentaires inner join sujets on commentaires.sujet_id = sujets.id
    where sujets.id = 12
);
```

I thought using QueryBuilder to retrieve the values 
I wanted but I realize it's quite complex ..
Here is one of my essays:

```html
DB::table('commentaires')->join('sujets', 
'sujets.id','=','commentaires.sujet_id')  
->where(['commentaires.id' => DB::raw('max(commentaires.id')])
->where('sujets.id','=', $unSujet->id)
->value('commentaires.auteur')
```

Or would you have a simpler idea?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Simpler idea would be to use [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) and define [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).

Eloquent provides a [great fluent interface](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) to connect models.
You'll be able to access the latest comment with:

```
ForumTopic::find($id)->commentaires()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()
```

You implement it in the model with a public function

**ForumTopic.php**

```
public function commentaires(){
    return $this->hasMany(Commentary::class);
}
```

Comment: Alright, it works ! Thank you very much for your help.